# Having trouble reading the output of my code

Tags: list, output

So the question was to return the difference between the maximum number and the smallest. My first code written was.

```
public int bigDiff(int[] nums) {
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(Math.max(max, nums[i]) == nums[i])
            max = nums[i];
        else if (Math.min(min, nums[i]) == nums[i])
            min = nums[i];

    }
    return max-min;
}
```

but this only outputs the largest number in the list.

Although, when I was just playing around and changed

```
int max = nums[0];
int min = nums[0];
```

it worked?, but I have no idea why. If anyone could understand how I would appreciate an explanation :D

Answer (score 0):

Imagine array of values: 1,2,3. The proper minumum is 1. But, you have initialized min to 0. No value from this array is less than 0, so, `min` remains 0. Whoops, the answer is wrong. The similar case: array of -1, -2, -3, and maximum inited to 0 - again, wrong result.

I know three standard approaches to fix this:

1. Maximum and minimum are inited to the first value of sequence (array, in your case). That is exactly how you fixed it - by setting to nums[0]. OTOH you needn't start with index 0 - 1 is good also (very minor optimization but worth noting).
2. Maximum is inited with a smallest value ever possible for this type (for int, it's `INT_MIN` from `<limits.h>`), and minumum - to possible maximal one (`INT_MAX`, respectively). Most likely both will be immediately updated with nums[0].
3. A boolean variable with meaning "no values yet" is tested, and direct assignment instead of comparing is used when it is set (in your case, with `i == 0` and immediately reset to false. It's a definitely overkill for a directly available integer array, but is good for cumbersome situations when comparing is inside of a callback instantiated through a template calling sequence, or another too-many-abstraction-levels design...

You have already warned that `else` is wrong, but, mathematically, it's allowed for my variants 1 and 3 (but not for variant 2! let you find out the fail proof by itself).

Comment: Thank you :D   15 characters

Answer (score -1):

When you was just playing around and changed `int max = nums[0]; int min = nums[0];` it **worked**.

Because, if you want to get the max num, you have to let variable `max` smaller than all of the member of arrary, then the function `max()` will make the `max` be the current maximum number。

So，the variable `min` must be larger then each member of the array!